# Java: Do i need to throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, setter

So I have to make a setter called `setSeconds(int seconds)`, and the integer seconds needs to be less than 60. Here's what I did:

```
public void setSeconds(int seconds){
    if (seconds<60) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Invalid seconds");
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if I have to throw an exception instead of printing `"Invalid Seconds"`. If so, do I have to use `try/catch` or `throws`?

Comment: Yes, if you want your program to do something on the basis of passing `seconds >= 60`. Printing to `System.out` is only useful to humans who happen to be looking at a console (or some external program into which the standard output is being piped).

Comment: Yes, `IllegalArgumentException` is appropriate for this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure if you "have to" throw an exception? It's your code... you don't "have to" do anything. It's usually better to throw an exception, for many reasons, but it is up to you.

Comment: *I'm not sure if I have to throw an exception*. We can't tell you that. It depends on your requirements. *If so, do I have to use try/catch or throws?* You have to use throws if you're throwing a *checked* exception. You would have to use try/catch if you want to catch the exception in another method. The details depend again on your specific requirements. This question is too vague and open-ended in its current form to give a useful answer.

Comment: Well it's obvious but nobody mentioned it yet: the value should probably also be >= 0.

Answer (score 3):

I think what your question is really about is the difference between a checked exception and an unchecked exception, and the different use-cases for each.

### What is a checked exception and when to use it ?

A checked exception is a any exception which directly or indirectly extends `Exception` but is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`. The compiler will enforce one of two things to be done when you call a method which throws a checked exception:

- either you need to add a `throws` clause to your method
- or you need to catch the exception

This is for forcing the developer to explicitely handle some exceptions that may require manual steps to fix what's broken. The typical use-case is IO operations which might fail, and we want to close any open resource even if the operation failed.

### What is an unchecked exception and when to use it ?

For programming errors or broken data, we usually use unchecked exceptions (any exception which extends `RuntimeException` and is therefore not compile-checked). No need to catch it or anything. A typical example is a string that cannot be parsed as an integer as it should, a pointer which is `null` while it was expected not to be etc...

It's pretty rare to try to recover from this type of exceptions, they're mostly here to prevent bad things to happen and tell the developer that something needs to be fixed.

### Now, what to do in your case ?

In your case, the `seconds` parameter could come either from other code calling your method, or from some data you are reading. There is nothing you want to do if the number of seconds is invalid, it just means someone is mis-using your program and you should put an end to it to fail safely (trying to recover from a programming error can lead to other problems or hide bugs for a long time).

Also, always think about making your exception messages useful and as complete as possible. The developer who is going to get the exception will thank you for adding the incorrect input to the message to help him debugging.

```
public void setSeconds(int seconds){
    if (seconds < 0 || 60 < seconds) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid seconds: " + seconds);
    }
    this.seconds = seconds;
}
```

Comment: "I think what your question is really about is the difference between a checked exception and an unchecked exception" I don't; I think OP is asking whether to use any sort of exception at all.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess I focused on the last part of the question. I think this answer still makes sense because it tries to give a sense of when it is right to use an exception, and which type of exception, when it is right to catch it etc. I'll make sure to add an answer more specific to the problem

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if I have to throw an exception instead of printing "Invalid Seconds".

If you want the caller of this method to be able to do something on the basis of passing `seconds >= 60`, you need to do something which the caller can intercept:

- Throw an exception
- Return a value (e.g. return `true` if the argument is OK, `false` if not)
- (or set some mutable state to indicate failure; but that's horrible).

Printing to `System.out` is only useful to humans who happen to be looking at a console (or some external program into which the standard output is being piped).

> If so, do I have to use try/catch or throws?

Neither:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid seconds");
```